# Argue positivity of mean value of an entanglement witness matrix for all separable state

Tags: entanglement

Given    $\
\hat{W}=\mathbf{1}_{A B}+\sigma_{x}^{A} \otimes \sigma_{x}^{B}-\sigma_{y}^{A} \otimes \sigma_{y}^{B}-\sigma_{z}^{A} \otimes \sigma_{z}^{B}
$

how can i show that for every separable state $\hat{\sigma}_{A B},\
\langle\hat{W}\rangle_{\rho} \equiv \operatorname{Tr}\left[\hat{W} \hat{\sigma}_{A B}\right]\geq 0$ ?
I have tried different things but the most promising seems to bee the following one. I know that if $\hat{\sigma}_{AB}^{T{A}}$ (partial transpose of $\hat{\sigma}_{AB}$ with respect to $A$
) is positive semi definite. Moreover I know that $\hat{W}_{AB}^{T{A}}$
is positive semi definite (I compute explicitly the matrix and its eigenvalues). My idea now was do to the following
\begin{equation}   Tr[\hat{W}_{AB}\hat{\sigma}_{AB}] = Tr[\hat{W}_{AB}(\hat{\sigma}_{AB}^{T{A}})^{T{A}}]    = Tr[\hat{W}_{AB}^{T{A}}\hat{\sigma}_{AB}^{T{A}}] = \ Tr[\sum_{k}\lambda_k{|\lambda}_k\rangle\langle{\lambda}_k|\hat{\sigma}_{AB}^{T{A}}] = \sum_{k}\lambda_k Tr[ \langle{\lambda}_k|\hat{\sigma}_{AB}^{T_{A}}|{\lambda}_k\rangle] \geq 0 \end{equation}
the problem here is that in the third inequality I use a technical lemma and i am not sure that I can apply it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you evaluate
$$
\text{Tr}(\hat W\sigma)=\text{Tr}((\hat W-2I)\sigma)+2.
$$
I've done this because $\hat W-2I$ is closely related to a projector onto a particular two-qubit state, $|\psi\rangle$ (I'm being deliberately vague here. Your question sounds like a homework question, so I'm leaving calculations for you to do). You should be able to use that to evaluate
$$
\max_{\phi_A,\phi_B}\langle\phi_A\phi_B|\psi\rangle.
$$

Comment: If you want specific help with that method, you should incorporate that into your question.